# nested for loop optimization

Tags: arrays, performance, memory, language-agnostic

This is the original code

```
for (j = 0; j <= 30; j++) {
  for (k = 0; k <= 30; k++) {
    x[j][k] = y[j][k] + z[j][k];
  }
}
```

And the code below is after applying a common sub-expression elimination optimization

```
for (j = 0; j <= 30; j++) {
  for (k = 0; k <= 30; k++) {
    t2 = C1 * j + W * k;
    x[t2] = y[t2] + z[t2];
  }
}
```

How does the common sub-expression elimination helps to improve performance in this case ? Its only array indices that is optimized ?

Comment: I think that codewise there is no optimization. The compiler would do that optimization implictly, I doubt that there would be any difference in performance in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any half-decent modern compiler will already be performing this optimisation.

Furthermore part of the index calculation should be hoisted into the outer loop:

```
for (j = 0; j <= 30; j++) {
  t1 = C1 * j;
  for (k = 0; k <= 30; k++) {
    t2 = t1 + W * k;
    x[t2] = y[t2] + z[t2];
  }
}
```

Comment: well your technique puts the loop invariant C1*j out, so you have done two optimization -> a CSE + loop invariant optimization.  Am i correct ?

Comment: There isn't much distinction in the naming here - it's really just two basic loop invariant optimisations. CSE is more commonly used to describe cases where you have two or more expressions with one ore more common subexpressions.

Answer (score 2):

It helps it because performing a 2D index performs an implicit multiplication and addition EACH TIME you do `[j][k]`. In the second one you are only performing that arithmetic ONCE (per loop iteration) and storing what's essentially `[j][k]` into `t2` and just reusing `t2`, instead of implicitly performing the `[j][k]` arithmetic THREE TIMES in the original code.

Of course, compilers are usually smart enough to know better, but I assumed you were just asking for the theory.